# How do I get a D-Link DWL-G520 working?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on an older desktop PC, and I am finding it much harder to connect to a wifi connection than it should be. I have an iPhone with which I want to tether to it with Mifi 4.0, but I need to install `ipheth` which I can't do without internet on that computer. I am typing from my other windows pc with which I can download and move hings with thumb drives, but haven't gotten keryx to work.

I also found a D-Link DWL-G520 HIGH SPEED 2.4GHZ (802.11G) WIRELESS 108MBPS PCI ADAPTER which I installed, but can't find a driver to put on a flashdrive to use it. If anybody has any ideas, they are appreciated. I don't want to have to move the comp. downstairs to plug into the modem.

PS: I also have a netgear USB network adapter, which doesn't work with my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

According to this wiki page:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsDlink

There are 2 kinds of D-Link DWL-G250's. Since yours isn't working I'm going to assume it's the ath5k based one.

> Works out of the box in Karmic, Precise. Does not work if prism54 is blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

So what you need to do is open this file by doing this in a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

it will then prompt you for your password. Find the line that says:

```
blacklist prism54
```

and then put a # in front of it so it says:

```
#blacklist prism54
```

Then save the file and reboot. That should make the card work. If it didn't please update your question with what happens. It would also help to know the *exact* model # and/or to provide the output of the command below (run in a terminal):

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```